# Null pointer exception when there is no value for numeric field in JSP

Tags: jsp, bean-validation

I am using bean to validate the form of JSP. If use setProperty and if some fields on the form is left blank it is throwing a null pointer exception. This exception is happening only if the field is happen to be numbers in the bean. I cant do validation without calling setProperty of bean. Is there any other way to do this ? The code i am using is as follows.

```
<jsp:useBean id="addBean" scope="request" class="org.mypackage.products.add_product6_Variables" />
    <jsp:setProperty name="addBean" property="*" />
```

My Error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /response.jsp at line 19

19: jsp:setProperty name="addBean" property="*" />

type Exception report

message 

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: error in invoking method
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:500)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:410)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)


root cause 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: error in invoking method
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.internalIntrospecthelper(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:361)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.introspecthelper(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:308)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.introspect(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:286)
    org.apache.jsp.response_jsp._jspService(response_jsp.java:77)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)


root cause 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: error in invoking method
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.createTypedArray(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:533)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.internalIntrospecthelper(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:350)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.introspecthelper(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:308)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.introspect(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:286)
    org.apache.jsp.response_jsp._jspService(response_jsp.java:77)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)


root cause 

java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:994)
    java.lang.Float.valueOf(Float.java:388)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.createTypedArray(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:516)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.internalIntrospecthelper(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:350)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.introspecthelper(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:308)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.introspect(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:286)
    org.apache.jsp.response_jsp._jspService(response_jsp.java:77)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your bean property type a primitive number or the wrapped object type? I mean int or Integer?

It probably is of type int now since int and other primitives cannot be set to null; while an Integer object can be set to null.

Can you change your bean property type to Integer etc and check whether the NPE still exists?

Comment: i dont really understand the term primitive number or the wrapper object type. can you tell me what it is ?? and my numeric field is float type.

Comment: See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class So if your bean code was public void setFloatProperty(float input) {...} change it to public void setFloatProperty(Float input) {...} . Notice the capital F in Float

Comment: Can you start your debugger and put a breakpoint at the line where you are getting the NPE? Check what is being passed in. Also, put the line that is causing the NPE in the 'Watch' window of your debugger.

Comment: i am checking that now.. will be back in a moment

Comment: Hmm, I had assumbed that Float class would be able to handle empty strings. As a last resort, you can change your bean property type to String instead of Float. And in your bean validation methods, you can first check whether the string is empty or not before converting it into a number.

Comment: is that the best way to do it ?